# WOW is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, webpack, wow.js

when I try to require `WOW` by one of those statements

```
global.WOW = require('wowjs');
var WOW = require('wowjs');
window.WOW = require('wowjs');
```

I receive this error

> jQuery.Deferred exception: WOW is not a constructor TypeError: WOW is not a constructor

Comment: try importing jQuery before using wowjs

Comment: I already did it

Comment: Ya, I think it would be tough to get a `jQuery.Deferred exception` if you didn't have jQuery yet.

Comment: Try `var Wow = require('wowjs').default;`

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
var Wow = require('wowjs').default;
require('bootstrap-sass');
require('bootstrap-hover-dropdown');
`
this is the statement

Answer (score 13):

try this one

```
const WOW = require('wowjs');

window.wow = new WOW.WOW({
    live: false
});

window.wow.init();
```

Answer (score 3):

the module exports an object, you need to use the WOW constructor in that object. Eg. `require('wowjs').WOW`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wow.js instead of wowjs in React

```
npm install wow.js
```

and in your code

```
import WOW from 'wow.js'

useEffect(() => {
    const wow = new WOW({ live: false }) // disables sync requirement
    wow.init()
}, [])
```